# Detect and process XML files when they appear in a known folder

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, service

### Background

A common way to integrate systems that know nothing of one another, such as banking software on mainframes and software on PCs, is to have one system, the provider (usually a mainframe, an AS400 or similar), export data to some well understood file format such as CSV or XML on a shared network file system, and then have the other system, the consumer, import and process the data. Typically the processing involves merging the data into a database for downstream access and processing, but this is not relevant to the transfer system.

A fundamental problem facing builders of such interfaces is how to coordinate the two systems with minimum latency, and ideally with a failure detection and reporting mechanism.

The oldest and crudest method is common scheduling: the provider emits the file at a scheduled time, and the consumer polls for the file at a scheduled time not long after. Margins are allowed for clock error and time is allowed for the file to be produced and copied, and at the appointed hour the consumer attempts to access the file and either processes it or reports that it couldn't.

This is a variety of polling optimised using foreknowledge of when the provider will provide.

The platform on which I have to implement this is Windows, and the technology available to me is C# and the .NET framework.

### The question

As I have never tried to do this on the Windows platform I need guidance from anyone with applicable experience. Is polling the right way to go about this, or if not what approach would you recommend? If the strategy you suggest introduces dependencies, what are they and what are their major consequences? For example if your approach requires a process to run all the time it should probably be implemented as a Windows Service.

I would really appreciate links to relevant material including any pertinent Stack Overflow Q&A so I can do the necessary self-education.

### Additional context

This is the requirement as it was presented to me:

I have a service that will provide me some XML files in regular interval to a folder e.g. C://Folder . In this folder, I have to check if a particular XML is there or not. Suppose File.XML should be in Folder at 12 noon then I have to run the window service to check folder of that file is in folder or not. If it is there then  I have to process it otherwise I have to log a alert that File was not available at 12 noon.

Comment: Instead of this you may go for file system watcher. Here event will get fired whenever a new file is added inside a perticular folder.

Comment: Can you help me with the code part so that I can take reference?

Comment: Shouting will take you nowhere on this site.

Comment: Don't be ridiculous it's not broad at all, it's a closed problem domain. It's very common and there are two standard solution architectures. All an answer needs is to frame and scope the solution, and point him at the documentation for the supporting technologies after explaining how the solution combines them.

Comment: I need guidance from anyone who can help me with above issue.

Comment: Ask how to implement a filewatcher on iseries.  I had one working at a former client.  Journal the ifs folder.  Then create a job to receive journal entries.  Then when you receive a commit.  It is the previous object received from the journal that is on the IFS.  Check if the previous object is your xml file if it is start processing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly interpret your requirements, you want a process to run whenever XML files are put into a specified folder, and you want to do this using C#.

There are two fundamental ways you can approach this problem.

1. Poll, which means check for files at regular intervals.
2. Use a `FileSystemWatcher`.

Polling is the strategy to which you allude in your question. You don't need to write a Windows Service to have a background task run at regular intervals. You can use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) to run a program at regular intervals. If you let Task Scheduler take care of the scheduling, all your program has to do is process any files it finds.

The other way relies on the fact that the NTFS file system raises events when files are created, modified, renamed or deleted. You can use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object to bind an event handler directly to any of these events. If you use this approach your program must not exit, so in this case a service is exactly what you need. A FileSystemWatcher can be set up to fire events for a particular folder and you can specify a file mask like `*.xml`

Either way, after you process each file I imagine you want to either remove it or mark it as processed.

Answer (score 0):

**First idea:**

1. You can use Quartz.NET [more info](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

   It is very good and easy task scheduler.
2. To easy create windows services I use TopShelf  [more info](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Example of configure `TopShelf` with `QuartzServer`

```
Host host = HostFactory.New(x =>
            {
                x.Service<IQuartzServer>(s =>
                {
                    s.SetServiceName("Services");
                    s.ConstructUsing(builder =>
                                            {
                                                IQuartzServer server = QuartzServerFactory.CreateServer();
                                                server.Initialize();
                                                return server;
                                            });
                    s.WhenStarted(server => server.Start());
                    s.WhenPaused(server => server.Pause());
                    s.WhenContinued(server => server.Resume());
                    s.WhenStopped(server => server.Stop());
                });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();

                x.SetDescription(Configuration.ServiceDescription);
                x.SetDisplayName(Configuration.ServiceDisplayName);
                x.SetServiceName(Configuration.ServiceName);
            });

            host.Run();
```

In this config You configure `QuarztServer` with windows services.

To create job You must implement `IJob` interface form Quartz namespace. In this implement You code all logic You need.

Then You can define `quaraz.xml` file with the job scheduler details with when job must start etc.

**Other approach:**

If You don't want to use external dlls as You mention in comments

You must create `WindowsService` from`Visual Studio template` and next You must implement the main method:

For example it is very simple and pure but my have got the main idea:

```
while(;;)
{
  if (Directory.GetFiles("path").Any())
  {
   //thre are some file
  }
 Thread.Sleep(50000);
}
```

Using LINQ with SELECT and WHERE statement You can filter what You want.

Comment: If I do not want to use Quartz.NET and Topshelf then how can I proceed.

Comment: @user6125167 You must create windows service and infinity loop witch have use Thread.Sleep method to 5 minut and then check the folder. You can use also File System Watcher class.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code part as well. So that I can take reference.

Comment: @user6125167 i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the Folder periodically you could also work event-driven with the FilesystemWatcher:

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = @"c:\my\path",
    Filter = "*.xml"
};

fsw.Created += (sender, args) =>
{
    // do whatever you like, args contains informations about the file that was created
};
```

**Advantages:**

- no need for complex job-scheduling
- event-driven, there is no delay
- you can also react on other events like changed or deleted

**Edit:**

If, you like to have more control over the events, than you could combine the FilesystemWatcher with the *[Reactive-Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET)*.

For example, you could use the *Buffer()* extension to collect all events over a timespan of x minutes but invoke the event-handler only once every x minutes.

Comment: Thanks Mike. However My requirement is to do with timer.

Comment: If `FileSystemWatcher` create the external thread? How It wokrs?